# Shader can be exported?

Tags: shaders

The only way to export shaders is by creating different maps ?(normal,roughness, mmetalic etc.)I want to sell a 3d model and i want to sell also the materials.Is possible?

Comment: I think this question have been already answered here :
[here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18362/exporting-multiple-materials-to-a-single-diffuse-specular-map)

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures